# Can't do anything with elements retrieved w/ class selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, object

I'm trying to set a .click function for the first element with a certain class - and each one will need separate code, incrementing my `purchase` function, with the first one using `purchase(0,0,1);` and the second using `purchase(0,1,1);` and so forth. While doing so with `$(".generation:first")` (with generation being said class) works, I want to be able to do this for all elements with this class, referring to them from an array, and for some reason

```
$(".generation")[0].click(function () { purchase(0,0,1); });
```

doesn't work - no errors or anything. It just doesn't seem to select it. Just the same later:

```
// Note: listings is an array of three different classes, 0 is .generation
// Therefore, 'listings[0][0]' should be identical to '$(".generation")[0]'
listings[0][0].find(".count").text(game.buildings[type][id].count+" bought");
```

The above won't work, stating `undefined is not a function`, if I use `.children(".count")` it instead says `object is not a function`.

Comment: If you edit your question to explain how you want to do `purchase(0,0,1)` on element 0 and `purchase(0,1,1)` on element 1 and so on (like you indicated in your comment to Arun), then I can reopen your question because it will no longer be a duplicate of the one it's marked as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `.eq(0)` to get the first element in a jQuery object.  `[0]` just gets you the first DOM object which obviously doesn't support the jQuery `.click()` method of adding an event handler.  So, you can do it like this:

```
$(".generation").eq(0).click(function () { purchase(0,0,1); });
```

---

If you want slightly different functionality for each `.generation` element as your comments now indicate, you can iterate with `.each()` and do something slightly different on each element.

```
$(".generation").each(function(index) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        purchase(0, index, 1);
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the click function on the jQuery object to register the handler for all elements with the said class

```
$(".generation").click(function () { purchase(0,0,1); });
```

The problem is the [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function is present in the jQuery object, but when you use `$(".generation")[0]` it returns a dom element reference which does not have the method thus you are getting the error.

---

In that case, you can find the index of the current element like

```
var $els = $(".generation").click(function () {
    purchase(0, $els.index(this), 1);
});
```

Comment: The problem with that is each one needs a different one, for example, `$(".generation")[1]` would need to do `purchase(0,1,1);` instead... EDIT: Thanks for telling why this happened!

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't think so - `If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.` - is my understanding wrong?

Comment: I see.  I didn't realize you were doing it on the jQuery object (I hadn't ever used it that way).  OK now.  I solved it a different way in my answer.